# Background Image of Div Take on Attribute Value

Tags: css

Is it possible to make the background image of a div be the value of an attribute.

For example:

```
<div bg="path_to_my_image">
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: is javascript an option?

Comment: Thanks @mmgross for your comment. I was trying to do this without javascript, so like we see with pseudo ellements the `attr` thingy. With javascript I know how to do but i was looking without js. Thx

Comment: Nope ... `bg` is only for `body` !! You can use class for this. Example http://jsfiddle.net/g0ptwkrg/

Comment: Aw drats ok thanks @Junaid i couldnt use class because the paths are user defined, it's for a firefox-addon so users pick paths on their local drive. So i cant pre-define classes :(

Comment: Instead of setting a bg attribute, you can set style attribute and add the background.

Comment: Could work with `attr()`, if there was actually a working implementation of it out there. So for the time being: No, won't work. If you really want something like that without javascript, maybe you can use php to generate css classes for each image...or what @anpsmn said, sometimes the obvious solutions elude me. ;)

Comment: Thanks @anpsmn that's what I'm resorting to but my purpose was user can set multiple attributes, name, value, etc etc and so i have a function that does `setAttribute`, `removeAttribute` but when it comes to background image im having to hook into it now and say `if bg then do style.backgroundImage = 'url('...` i was trying to avoid that hook :(

Comment: Thanks all i really appreciate all your answers!

Comment: @Noitidart: you *might* be able to use that **attr** option [within the css url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

Comment: @jbutler483 At some time in the future ...

Comment: Thanks @jbutler483 i tried that and it didnt work thats why i posted this topic :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no "bg" attribute so far in html, instead of this you can use inline style to set the background for a particular div.

example:

```
<div style="background:url(sample-image.jpg)"></div>
```

[refer the code here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/wruka3xw/)

Comment: please don't recommend inline styling, which is bad practise, whilst other methods are available (i.e. javascript/etc).

Comment: @jbutler483 i'm not asking him to use the inline style for the div, instead i suggested this way which he can use it under some class name.

Comment: thanks again @jbutler483 and vasanth i apprecaite it!